# Golang: Installation directory error?

Tags: go

I have the error:

```
go install: no install location for directory /Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/src outside GOPATH
```

I'm using go version 1.1 on OS X.

I can build & run but can't install packages.

My environment:

```
GOPATH=/Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/bin
```

Project tree:

```
/Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project
bin
pkg
src
```

I can build without error:

```
..:src xwilly$ go build test.go 
..:src xwilly$ go install test.go
go install: no install location for directory /Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/src outside GOPATH
```

Here is a simple example:

```
xwilly$ cat test.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Bonjour")
}
xwilly$ go run test.go 
Bonjour
xwilly$ go install test.go 
go install: no install location for directory /Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/src/learning outside GOPATH
```

Comment: what's the package name in test.go?

Comment: the package name is =>  package main

Comment: You can not install `package main`. Read [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: @Tom: You can `go install` `package main`. It's how Go commands are installed.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [GOPATH environment variable](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable)
>
> Each directory listed in `GOPATH` must have a prescribed structure:
>
> The `src/` directory holds source code. The path below '`src`' determines
>   the import path or executable name.
>
> The `pkg/` directory holds installed package objects. As in the Go tree,
>   each target operating system and architecture pair has its own
>   subdirectory of `pkg` (`pkg/GOOS_GOARCH`).
>
> If `DIR` is a directory listed in the `GOPATH`, a package with source in
>   DIR/src/foo/bar can be imported as "`foo/bar`" and has its compiled form
>   installed to "`DIR/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/foo/bar.a`".
>
> The `bin/` directory holds compiled commands. Each command is named for
>   its source directory, but only the final element, not the entire path.
>   That is, the command with source in `DIR/src/foo/quux` is installed into
>   DIR/bin/quux, not `DIR/bin/foo/quux`. The `foo/` is stripped so that you
>   can add `DIR/bin` to your `PATH` to get at the installed commands. If the
>   `GOBIN` environment variable is set, commands are installed to the
>   directory it names instead of `DIR/bin`.
>
> Here's an example directory layout:
>
> ```
> GOPATH=/home/user/gocode
>
> /home/user/gocode/
>     src/
>         foo/
>             bar/               (go code in package bar)
>                 x.go
>             quux/              (go code in package main)
>                 y.go
>     bin/
>         quux                   (installed command)
>     pkg/
>         linux_amd64/
>             foo/
>                 bar.a          (installed package object)
> ```

Your directory structure is wrong. You are trying to install a command (`package main`). It should be in a source directory named after your command. See the `quux` command above.

In your case, assume your command is going to be named `billy`.

```
$ mkdir -p /Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/src/billy
```

which is inside your `GOPATH`. Move your `test.go` file to this directory. Run

```
$ go install billy
```

The command `billy` should, unless you have set `GOBIN`, be installed in the

```
/Users/xwilly/Dropbox/go/project/bin
```

directory inside your `GOPATH`, which should be in your `PATH`.

Comment: +1 thanks for great explanation. I missed the `gobin` bit in the docs