# `go get` command fails: unrecognized import path "_/<path>"

Tags: go, get, gopath

Basically, my question is, why is it putting an underscore in front of my import path?

It says `import path does not begin with hostname` which I'm assuming is because it starts with an underscore.

I read somewhere this may have something to do with me screwing up my GOPATH, but I've tried moving it everywhere, inside the project folder, outside the project folder, in the default location, etc.

I'm new to go and this has come up a few times recently. Would appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score -1):

So I was misunderstanding where my source code had to be.

For anyone in the same boat, it needs to be within the go path in the actual `src` folder.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524392/golang-installation-directory-error) helpful.